# Como se referir a uma String através de diversos valores em Java (Android)?

Tags: java, android, string

Eu fiz um chatbot/assistente virtual e eu quero que ele responda uma mesma coisa para palavras diferentes, exemplo: se eu escrever "Oi" ou escrever "Olá" ele devolver uma mesma resposta: "Olá, como posso ajudar".

```
public void assistente(View view) {
    if (caixa.getText().toString().equals(cumprimento) {

        resposta.setText("Olá, como posso te ajudar?");
        rosto.setImageResource(R.drawable.normal);

    } 

resposta.setText("Olá, como posso te ajudar?"); 

} 

String cumprimento = "Olá"; //Nessa parte eu quero colocar outros valores
```

Eu uso o Android Studio 3.0.1. Sou muito iniciante em programação, por favor, explique da forma mais fácil possível. Muito obrigado!

Comment: A sua questão não está clara o suficiente ? Apenas tem essa pergunta e resposta ? Como iria funcionar se a pessoa escrevesse outra coisa?

Answer (score 0):

*Usa a Class StringBuilder* https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

public void assistente(View view) {
    if (caixa.getText().toString().equals(cumprimento) {

        resposta.setText("Olá, como posso te ajudar?");
        rosto.setImageResource(R.drawable.normal);

    } 

resposta.setText("Olá, como posso te ajudar?"); 

sb.append(" Outro texto ").append("Ok");

} 

sb.append("Olá").append(" Teste"); //Nessa parte eu quero colocar outros valores
```

*De acordo com a sua logica você vai construindo sua resposta. *

Comment: Eu não entendi como eu coloco no código porque ele afirma haver muitos erros

Comment: Coloca o StringBuilder no escopo  da classe se você quiser usar em outros métodos.

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi direito o que você pretende, você poderia fazer algo assim:

```
    ArrayList<String> cumprimentos = new ArrayList<String>();
    cumprimentos.add("oi");
    cumprimentos.add("blz");
    cumprimentos.add("Olá");

 public void assistente(View view) {
 if (cumprimentos.contains(caixa.getText().toString())) {

    resposta.setText("Olá, como posso te ajudar?");
    rosto.setImageResource(R.drawable.normal);

  } 

    resposta.setText("Olá, como posso te ajudar?"); 

}
```

Comment: Entendi e até deu certo, obrigado! Mas quando eu coloco um complemento a mais como, ex.: if (cumprimentos.contains(caixa.getText().toString()) + " ,tudo bem") ele executa, mas não funciona.

Comment: Se sua lógica for pra pegar uma palavra de "Olá", "Oi", etc. dentro de uma frase você pode fazer assim: 

String sentence = "Check this answer and you can find the keyword with this code";
String search  = "keyword";

if ( sentence.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) != -1 ) { /*resto da lógica*/ }.